# CMake phony target which duplicates another target

Tags: c++, c, cmake, makefile, build

I am trying to "duplicate" a target in my CMake file without maintaining 2 targets and all it's dependencies.

For example I have a main target MyBigLibrary

```
add_library(MyBigLibrary STATIC "")
target_compile_definitions(MyBigLibrary PRIVATE definitions..)
target_include_directories(MyBigLibrary PUBLIC public_directories..)
target_include_directories(MyBigLibrary PRIVATE private_directories..)
target_link_libraries(MyBigLibrary INTERFACE libraries..)
...
...
target_sources(MyBigLibrary ..source files..)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a identical copy of MyBigLibrary target (e.g. MyBigLibraryModified) which then I can feed to external script via add_custom_command.

I know there is way to have 2 targets, but then you have maintain 2 targets and all of it's dependencies.

Is there a way to have a phony target, e.g MyBigLibraryModified which is built only MyBigLibrary, and inherits INTERFACE flags as a dependencies?

Comment: `I am trying to "duplicate" a target in my CMake file without maintaining 2 targets and all it's dependencies.` This is clearly [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain what is the actual goal not means to it. Why you think you need two identical targets and how `add_custom_command` relates to that.

Comment: can't `MyBigLibraryModified` just link to `MyBigLibrary`?

Comment: @MarekR it's not XY problem. add_custom_command will obfuscate the symbols of MyBigLibraryModified, which later other executables can link to it and use it.

Comment: So problem X is that you want to add a new target that depends on your existing target and adds another step. And your problem Y is to make a copy of existing target. For make I think that would be rather straight forward but for CMake I don't really know

Comment: You are asking question which is weird as examples in a link. I have no idea what `add_custom_command will obfuscate the symbols` suppose to mean. You are clearly focused on your solution not on actual problem. Are you trying strip symbols from release version of your target?

Comment: @MarekR that is correct.

Comment: What does prevent you from stripping symbols from the library `MyBigLibrary` itself, instead of creating its copy?

Comment: I know no direct way in CMake for create a target which "is a copy of another target but **replaces** some its properties" (In your case you wanted to replace the library's file). Using INTERFACE library you could only **add** some properties, like include directories. But you cannot replace existing ones.

Comment: @AlanBirtles As far as I know, you can't just link library A to library B, without providing a single source file to library B. So that option doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to create two different libraries containing the same compiled objects but with different features, I used the `OBJECT` library type containing all the source files, then I created two different libraries that listed the `OBJECT` target in their `target_link_libraries`.

The `OBJECT` library in CMake is still not fully correct, even after years of waiting for it to be enhanced, but it works mostly OK in most situations these days.

See [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Comments under question:

> - ... Are you trying strip symbols from release version of your target? –
>   `Marek R`
> - @MarekR that is correct. – `pureofpure`

So you are doing that wrong. You do not need (and you should not have) separate target for stripped version of your library/application.

For stripped version build proves is just a bit different.

One way to do it is just do:

```
$ cmake --install . --prefix PathWithResultsWithSybols  .....
$ cmake --install . --prefix PathWithStripedResults --strip ....
```

See [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project)

Comment: That is not correct. I don 't understand why I am doing it wrong. I have 2 targets which are static libraries - one I ship to some costumers as it is, the other one I need to obfuscate and strip some symbols. I have custom script for that, since default "strip" it strips only debug symbols. Some "Test" executables links with "stripped" version and other (unittests) links with non-stripped version.  Hope that make sense.

Comment: There are some standards and common ways to do it and I never seen anybody was doing this your way. Shipping library is usually started by using `install` step which has an option to strip library. This is what is was design to do.